# Automate Application - How to answer a prompt in a batch file

Tags: automation

Really appreciate an answer.

The application I am running, requires a user id and password immediately to be input manually. The application is run at dos command prompt.  How can i include this in a batch file (ie. the application to be executed, user id and password in a batch file ) without any user intervention, to run.

Ireshad

Answer (score 2):

You can use VBScript to do that.  Use AppActivate to bring the window onto the screen:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.AppActivate "notepad"
```

Then use SendKeys to send the required keys:

```
'Wait a second before we do anything
WScript.sleep 1000

intCount=0

'Send the keys to notepad application
Do While intCount <= 10
  wshShell.SendKeys "Line No: " 
  wshShell.SendKeys intCount 
  wshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 

  intCount = intCount + 1
Loop

'Quit
WScript.Quit
```

Sources:

- AppActivate: http://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html
- SendKeys: http://en.allexperts.com/q/Visual-Basic-1048/2008/10/Press-key-using-vbs.htm