# windows batch script: how to run an executable and answer prompts from the executable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an old executable that runs on the command line. It prompts the user interactively for specific pieces of information. What I would like to do is to wrap the all the interaction of this command into a batch script so that it just runs and answers the prompts *without a user having to interact*.

This is different from simply executing a command with arguments. The executable prompts the user. Paraphrasing the way it works...

```
C:\MyDir>legacy.exe
  Welcome to old program.

  Please enter your name:
  > John Smith

  How many widgets are you buying:
  > 47

 Great, generating the PO file now...
 Goodbye.
```

Ideally, I would like to actually wait for the prompts and respond to each accordingly. I can do that in .NET with the Process object, but I'd like to attempt this using a windows batch script. If I can't parse the prompts and just need to blindly dump arguments, I'll take that as well.

I see [another question where the answer was to use VBScript](https://superuser.com/questions/615403/automate-application-how-to-answer-a-prompt-in-a-batch-file). Is there a way to do this in plain batch script?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way your `legacy.exe` interacts with (redirected) standardinput.

You can try this

```
(Echo John Smith&Echo 47)|legacy.exe
```

If that doesn't work you may need a 3rd party `sendkey.exe` and detach legacy.exe from the batch with start as suggested by [Genaro Morales](https://superuser.com/users/740568/genaro-morales) and use the sendkey app to do the input in a similar way the vbs solution does. So this isn't **pure** batch. See [these search results.](http://www.google.com/search?q=dostips.com+sendkey)

Comment: Thanks, it appears that in my particular case I can't use "echo" to feed input to my commandline executable. Will need to investigate sendkey and vbscript solutions.

Comment: Turns out that vbscript + wsh (windows script host) w/sendkeys is the lowest friction way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever tried to get a batch file with:

start "fullpath" legacy.exe   ?

Comment: No... can you elaborate? Doesn't start simply open a new command window and execute the given command.

Comment: the start instruction opens a new command window and runs the exe or the batch file you put on the arguments (running as start /B runs the exe in the same command window opened by the batch), I'm not pretty sure if you only want to run the program from a batch file or if you are attempting to get the same behaviour that the exe has in the batch script

Comment: @Genaro Morales why don't you edit your answer and write the information needed in order to elaborate your answer